# parallax Scrolling not working in coordinator layout?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-coordinatorlayout

> I am developing news app and I have implemented coordinatorlayout but
>   it is not giving  parallax Scrolling effect in webview I still dont understand what is wrong with my code below.
>   I am developing news app and I have implemented coordinatorlayout but
>   it is not giving  parallax Scrolling effect in webview I still dont understand what is wrong with my code below.

my xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

below my DetailActivity.java file

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
Toolbar toolbar;
@BindView(R.id.imageView)
ImageView imageView;
@BindView(R.id.webView)
WebView webView;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    String imageUrl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("imageKey");
    Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(imageView);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    String url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("urlKey");


    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.loadUrl(url);


}


@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

}